# Can we create an anti package using Sitecore courier?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am working on a devops project where I need to compare the latest build with the current build in the sitecore instance and create an update package. I am doing this with the help of Sitecore Courier. I would also like to create an anti package for the same. Please let me know if it can be accomplished using Sitecore courier.

Comment: It's not possible with Courier, but possible with [Sitecore PowerShell Extensions module](http://xcentium.com/blog/2015/11/10/sitecore-and-powershell) which you may be able to script into your CI.

Comment: Can we reverse the source and target and create an anti package using Sitecore courier?

Comment: That _should_ work but you would need to test it. Also take note of *what* you are comparing, only items checked into Source Control or live content? If what you are worried about is rollback after deployments then suggest you also take a full db backup before the deployment.

Comment: We are comparing sitecore items in source control. Our target is to create an package which will compare the last two deployment folders and only contain the updates made in the latest build.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Not sure why an anti-package is required for this though, an anti-package is to revert any changes what an installation causes. Have a read of [this](http://sitecoresnippets.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/sitecore-courier-effortless-packaging.html) and [this](http://goblinrockets.com/2013/11/03/continuous-integration-deployment-with-sitecore/) but you essentially need to be tagging your source control system.

Comment: I will.. Thanks jammykam!

Comment: Possible approach/idea for anti package can be seen here: http://www.xcentium.com/blog/2015/11/10/sitecore-and-powershell It is using PowerShell module but present interesting idea.